# openvpn host-to-host access subnet home to remote

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, openvpn

I am not so good with networking and am trying to remotely control some computers on another network. I have set up a VPN via and AWS AMI image setup for openvpn. The AWS machine is on EC2 with a static public IP address. I can connect both home and remote computer to this VPN and I can SSH on the remote.

I am trying to get home pc to talk to remote pc subnet. I can talk from home pc to remote pc, but I can not talk to the computers on the remote pc subnet..

Subnet A is infact 10.1.6.0/24 and subnet B is 10.1.1.0/24

I assume some manual routing is required at either end but I have no idea where to put that.

The other idea was to put open vpn on each remote PC but I want to avoid that if possible.

[OpenVPN client A to client B subnet communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLrib.png)

A few other posts around with the same issue but i could not understand them - https://serverfault.com/questions/861870/how-to-let-an-openvpn-client-access-to-another-clients-subnet ... but the OP link to a stackoverflow post has been taken down for some reason.

https://serverfault.com/questions/480069/how-to-force-all-traffic-through-vpn

Answer (score 0):

What I do is run another server on the client that I want to get to its network.  It's not that much overhead.  On the client you need to make sure it's using a bridge and run these commands (on Linux):

```
brctl addif br0 tap0
ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
```

Make sure `client-to-client` is enabled on all servers.  I can access the local network of all of my clients this way.  You need to have two TAP adapters from the connecting PC: one for the Amazon OpenVPN server, and another for the client's server.

Comment: thanks @xinthose: When you say "run another server on the client that I want to get to its network", what does that mean? What additional server would you recommend, like another VPN server, on 10.1.1.5?

Comment: @craba correct; OpenVPN can run as a client and server simultaneously; for the client's server, use a different subnet than the AWS server, your local network, and the remote network, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I believe this web link has a great answer: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=9465

Answer (score 0):

found here: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=9465

The author has 4 methods, 2 and 3 solve my use case, i left the 4th out as it was quite lengthy.

Site A
Local network is 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0.
Default gateway have IP 192.168.0.1 (the common configuration).
Ip of the host running OpenVPN is 192.168.0.A, where A may be any from 2 to 254.
The hosts have IPs like 192.168.0.x, where x is 2 to 254 and different from A (the OpenVPN's host's IP).

Site B
Local network is 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0.
Default gateway have IP 192.168.1.1 (the common configuration).
Ip of the host running OpenVPN is 192.168.1.B, where B may be any from 2 to 254.
The hosts have IPs like 192.168.1.x, where x is 2 to 254 and different from B (the OpenVPN's host's IP).

The VPN IP's are from 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0.

In discussing this mater it is not important which site is server or client, and what IPs get the TAP interfaces. To resolve this routing issue there are 4 methods:

**Method 1**
As obvious it is, move the OpenVPN software to the LAN's default gateway. As there are situation where this is not possible (a simple router which can't run OpenVPN), this method is the best for future expandings, as adding more remote sites will not involve on return to the routing issues.

**Method 2**
Adding a static route for remote network to the every host's routing table. On every hosts we have to add a route like this:
CODE: SELECT ALL

route add  mask  gw 
For example, on every host from site A we have to add two routes:
CODE: SELECT ALL

route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.A
route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.A
The route for VPN network 10.8.0.0 can be ommited, but it is not recommended.

The same way we add routes on the Site B, to show the hosts where to route the packets for remote site:
CODE: SELECT ALL

route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.B
route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.B
If there will be a 3rd site, we must add another route for the new remote network in the same way.

The routes have to be added on default LAN's gateways too. Althought, it seems that many routers are able to return responces back without adding routers for the remote networks.

**Method 3**
This method implies adding same routes as in method 2 only on the LAN's default gateway. So the redirecting will be held by the router and we don't need to add routes on every host. Of course, this is possible if the router permits modifying routing table and iptable.
As in method 2, on the default router we add routes to remote sites:
CODE: SELECT ALL

route add  mask  gw 
For example, on default gateway of the site A with IP 192.168.0.1 we have to add two routes:
CODE: SELECT ALL

route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.A
route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.A
But this will only show the gateway where to send packets originating from itself. We also need to show how to route packets for remote site from local hosts. For this we have to add a rule to the routers iptable which will tell that all packets incoming from LAN interface and have the destination to the remote site network must be redirected to the OpenVPN host. Most routers which handle wider customization have the ability to use unix like command "iptables". So, we use the iptables rule like this:
CODE: SELECT ALL

iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i  -d / -j ROUTE --gw 
For example, on default router from site A we will add:
CODE: SELECT ALL

iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i  -d 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.0.A
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i  -d 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.0.A
The same way we add rules on the default router from site B.

If we add a 3rd site, then we will have to add to the other sites a route to the 3rd site network in the same way.